# Extremely poor accuracy upon training network from scratch

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, resnet, imagenet, custom-training

I am trying to retrain resnet50 from scratch using a dataset that is similar to ImageNet. I wrote the following training loop:

```py
def train_network(epochs , train_loader , val_loader , optimizer , network):
    since = time.time ( )
    train_acc_history = []
    val_acc_history = []

    best_model_weights = copy.deepcopy (network.state_dict ( ))
    best_accuracy = 0.0

    for epoch in range (epochs):
        correct_train = 0
        correct_val = 0
        for x , t in train_loader:
            x = x.to (device)
            t = t.to (device)
            optimizer.zero_grad ( )
            z = network (x)
            J = loss (z , t)
            J.backward ( )
            optimizer.step ( )

            _ , y = torch.max (z , 1)
            correct_train += torch.sum (y == t.data)

        with torch.no_grad ( ):
            network.eval ( )
            for x_val , t_val in val_loader:
                x_val = x_val.to (device)
                t_val = t_val.to (device)
                z_val = network (x_val)
                _ , y_val = torch.max (z_val , 1)
                correct_val += torch.sum (y_val == t_val.data)

        network.train ( )
        train_accuracy = correct_train.float ( ) / len (train_loader.dataset)
        val_accuracy = correct_val.float ( ) / len (val_loader.dataset)
        print (
            F"Epoch: {epoch + 1} train_accuracy: {(train_accuracy.item ( ) * 100):.3f}% val_accuracy: {(val_accuracy.item ( ) * 100):.3f}%" ,
            flush = True)

        # time_elapsed_epoch = time.time() - since
        # print ('Time taken for Epoch {} is {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format (epoch + 1, time_elapsed_epoch // 60 , time_elapsed_epoch % 60))

        if val_accuracy > best_accuracy:
            best_accuracy = val_accuracy
            best_model_weights = copy.deepcopy (network.state_dict ( ))
        train_acc_history.append (train_accuracy)
        val_acc_history.append (val_accuracy)

    print ( )

    time_elapsed = time.time ( ) - since
    print ('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format (time_elapsed // 60 , time_elapsed % 60))
    print ('Best Validation Accuracy: {:3f}'.format (best_accuracy * 100))

    network.load_state_dict (best_model_weights)
    return network , train_acc_history , val_acc_history
```

But I am getting extremely poor training and validation accuracies as below:

```
> Epoch: 1 train_accuracy: 3.573% val_accuracy: 3.481%                  
> Epoch: 2 train_accuracy: 3.414% val_accuracy: 3.273%                  
> Epoch: 3 train_accuracy: 3.515% val_accuracy: 4.039%                  
> Epoch: 4 train_accuracy: 3.567% val_accuracy: 4.195%
```

Upon googling, I found that the accuracies of training from scratch are usually not so poor (in fact they start off from around 40% - 50%). I am finding it difficult to understand where the glitch might be. It would be great if someone could help me figure out where I might be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: This [blog post](https://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) has a checklist of things that can help with your debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your training loop without the weight checkpoint and got accuracy over 90% on fashionMNIST dataset using my own ResNet. So if you are using a good loss/optimizer I would suggest looking at the network architecture or creation of the data-loaders.

```
def train_network(epochs , train_loader , val_loader , optimizer , network):
    #since = time.time ( )
    train_acc_history = []
    val_acc_history = []
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    #best_model_weights = copy.deepcopy (network.state_dict ( ))
    #best_accuracy = 0.0

    for epoch in range (epochs):
        correct_train = 0
        correct_val = 0
        network.train ( )
        for x , t in train_loader:
            x = x.to (device)
            t = t.to (device)
            optimizer.zero_grad ( )
            z = network (x)
            J = loss (z , t)
            J.backward ( )
            optimizer.step ( )
            _ , y = torch.max (z , 1)
            correct_train += torch.sum (y == t.data)

        with torch.no_grad ( ):
            network.eval ( )
            for x_val , t_val in val_loader:
                x_val = x_val.to (device)
                t_val = t_val.to (device)
                z_val = network (x_val)
                _ , y_val = torch.max (z_val , 1)
                correct_val += torch.sum (y_val == t_val.data)

        network.train ( )
        train_accuracy = correct_train.float ( ) / len (train_loader.dataset)
        val_accuracy = correct_val.float ( ) / len (val_loader.dataset)
        print (
            F"Epoch: {epoch + 1} train_accuracy: {(train_accuracy.item ( ) * 100):.3f}% val_accuracy: {(val_accuracy.item ( ) * 100):.3f}%" ,
            flush = True)
    '''
        if val_accuracy > best_accuracy:
            best_accuracy = val_accuracy
            best_model_weights = copy.deepcopy (network.state_dict ( ))
        train_acc_history.append (train_accuracy)
        val_acc_history.append (val_accuracy)


    #time_elapsed = time.time ( ) - since
    #print ('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format (time_elapsed // 60 , time_elapsed % 60))
    print ('Best Validation Accuracy: {:3f}'.format (best_accuracy * 100))

    #network.load_state_dict (best_model_weights)
    '''
    return network , train_acc_history , val_acc_history

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
train_network(10,trainloader, testloader, optimizer, net)
```

```
Epoch: 1 train_accuracy: 83.703% val_accuracy: 86.820%
Epoch: 2 train_accuracy: 88.893% val_accuracy: 89.400%
Epoch: 3 train_accuracy: 90.297% val_accuracy: 89.700%
Epoch: 4 train_accuracy: 91.272% val_accuracy: 90.640%
Epoch: 5 train_accuracy: 91.948% val_accuracy: 91.250%
...
```

So, if you tested with the training loop I used (yours with small mods) and it still doesn't work I would check data loader and play around with network architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out that the model starts off with very low accuracies on my dataset, but eventually picks up a good accuracy after a few epochs. I used pretrained = False, so I think different weight initializations and different datasets different accuracies. I too tried the loop with a different dataset and got good accuracies from the first epoch.